# How do you change the date modified on a file?

Tags: windows, windows-10, batch-file, file-management, properties

I recorded many photos and videos with an Akoso action camera, but I never thought to change the camera's stored time. Only after creation of the files did I see that date and time stamps were saved on top of the files. While I cannot change the images without editing them, I am hoping I can at least change the file properties.

Any way to change these date/time file properties? If so, even if just a simple script, I could then batch something for a larger folder of such pictures.
Preferably I can input some offset.

Comment: Are you talking about the date/tome stamps from the file system of the image files, or about the EXIF (or similar) data embedded in the images? For the former, you can use almost every scripting language (although I recommend *not* to use [tag:batch-file] as it does not support date/time data types); for the latter, you have to use some image/EXIF (batch) editor anyway...

Comment: @aschipfl - I was asking about the former, having given up on the latter (if you have any ideas I'm all ears!). Are you suggesting that similar to `mv` in bash, as used to change file names, there is an easy way to change file properties?

Answer (score 1):

I occasionally use [BulkFileChanger](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/bulk_file_changer.html) by NirSoft.

The latest version also supports batch edits.

"BulkFileChanger is a small utility that allows you to create files list from multiple folders, and then make some action on them - Modify their created/modified/accessed time, change their file attribute (Read Only, Hidden, System), run an executable with these files as parameter, and copy/cut paste into Explorer."

Answer (score 1):

If you have the touch program installed, or if you can get it installed, open the command prompt and type:

```
touch -d "2020-11-01" file
```

Comment: I was able to run on Windows with Git Bash.

Answer (score 0):

If I may promote my own tool: [SKTimeStamp](https://tools.stefankueng.com/SKTimeStamp.html)

After installing it, you can select the files in the Windows Explorer, right click and chose Properties from the context menu. Then in the properties dialog you'll find a new tab where you can modify the file times and dates easily.
[image]

It's open source, source code can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/stefankueng/tools/tree/master/SKTimeStamp)